# What could be an example where multiplying two power series gives a bigger radius that is not infinity

Tags: calculus, power-series

I'm trying to think of an example of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nx^n$ with radius of convergence $R_1,R_2$ such that when we multiply them we get  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^n, c_n = \sum_{i+j=n}a_ib_j=\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_jb_{n-j}$ with radius $R$ such that $R>R_1$, $R>R_2$ and $R<\infty$. What could be an easy example for that?

Answer (score 4):

Consider the Taylor series $\sum_{k\geq0} a_k\,x^k$  of the functions
$$f(x):={2-x\over(1-x)(3-x)},\qquad g(x):={1-x\over 2-x}\ .$$
Then $R_f=1$, $\>R_g=2$, and $R_{fg}=3$, because the radius of convergence for the Taylor series at $0$ is equal to the distance from $0$ to the nearest singularity.

Comment: Why is that true? Why does $R_f=1, R_g=2$? I am having trouble calculating the taylor series...